# How to insert R-Table from (15, 15) to (255 states, 4 actions)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, q-learning

I'm setting up a R-table with (255 states, 4 actions). How do I input it from R-table (15, 15)?

I have created R-table (15, 15), but turn out I have to make R-table (225, 4) for the homework.

```
r_matrix = np.array([
[-1, -2, -3, -2, -3, -3, -4, -1, -4, -2, -1, -2, -3, -3, 500],
[-1, -3, -1, -2, -4, -1, -4, -1, -4, -2, -4, -2, -2, -2, -1],
[-4, -2, -1, -4, -2, -1, -2, -4, -2, -3, -2, -1, -2, -4, -4],
[-4, -2, -4, -1, -3, -2, -3, -2, -4, -2, -4, -1, -2, -4, -2],
[-4, -2, -2, -3, -2, -3, -1, -1, -4, -2, -1, -3, -4, -2, -4],
[-4, -3, -3, -4, -2, -3, -4, -2, -2, -1, -1, -2, -1, -2, -1],
[-2, -3, -2, -1, -1, -3, -2, -1, -4, -3, -1, -1, -2, -3, -3],
[-3, -1, -1, -4, -4, -3, -1, -2, -3, -1, -1, -4, -4, -3, -3],
[-3, -1, -4, -2, -3, -3, -1, -4, -4, -4, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1],
[-3, -4, -4, -2, -3, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -3, -4, -3, -4, -1],
[-3, -4, -1, -1, -1, -4, -4, -4, -4, -1, -2, -4, -2, -2, -1],
[-1, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -4, -1, -2, -4, -1, -2, -4],
[-2, -2, -1, -2, -2, -2, -4, -3, -1, -4, -1, -4, -2, -2, -2],
[-2, -1, -3, -1, -4, -4, -1, -3, -3, -1, -1, -2, -3, -4, -3],
[-2, -2, -1, -4, -4, -4, -2, -2, -3, -1, -2, -2, -1, -1, -3]
])

# Result (Up, Right, Down, Left)
r_matrix2 = np.array(
    [None, -2, -1, None],
    [None, -3, -3, -1],
    [None, -2, -1, -2],
    [None, -3, -2, -3],
    [None, -3, -4, -2],
    ...
)
```

Thank you

Comment: How do you intend to turn 225 elements `(15, 15)` into 900 `(225, 4)`?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear. Basically, the teacher ask us to create R-table for Q-Learning. He gives us 225 elements (15, 15). The R-table will be (255 states, 4 actions).

Comment: Okay, so where do the actions come from?

Comment: Up, Right, Down, Left from the current state. Basically if I was on state (0, 0), it will be [None, -2, -1, None]

Comment: Each value corresponds to a reward value for an action taken from a state, right? Where do the *values* come from?

Answer (score 0):

To learn a policy that maximizes reward you apparently
want to do Reward Backpropagation (or Value Iteration)
for 225 location vertices with (symmetric) in-degree 4.

(BTW, you twice mentioned `255` where I think you meant `225`.)

Arbitrarily define `bad` as `-1000`; substitute `None` values with that "negative infinity" reward.

There is a modeling detail at the Goal node containing reward of 500:
ensure that all four outward edges have `bad` reward,
so an agent won't be tempted to go there and then follow a cycle that
permits unending collection of the 500 reward.

## diameter

Compute the diameter of your grid-world graph.
By inspection, trivially, it is the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) of 28, twice 15 - 1.
For arbitrary graphs you may need a [shortest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) algorithm to determine this.

## init

Initialize the value of all non-Goal location vertices to `bad`.

## iteration

For `v` in all location vertices,
remember previous value `val`. Then
chase the outward edges to an adjacent location,
find the (typically negative) reward of traversing the edge,
and store the updated value of `v` as max(val, val + reward),
evaluated across all four edges.

The interpretation is: if we land on a location having value `val`,
we are confident that by following an optimal policy
we could collect `val` reward points.

This concludes an iteration.
Repeat, for `diameter` iterations.
After the first one,
we will have updated just three values, to 497, 498, & 499.
After the second at least five more values will be updated, and so on,
gradually whittling away until no more `bad` values remain.

## traversal

Now traversing the graph from Start to Goal is straightforward.
Across all four out-edges,
simply follow the edge that leads to the highest-value location,
and repeat until encountering the Goal.